# How to compute memoized data within an event handler

Tags: reactjs

In my React component I want to access the results of memoization inside the event handler that fetched the data that's being memoized, like this:

```
const [theData, setTheData] = React.useState(null)

const memoizedData = React.useMemo(() => {
  return someComplexProcessOn(theData)
}, [theData])

const buttonClick = async () => {
  const newData = await fetchTheData()
  setTheData(newData)
  // now I want to access memoizedData
}
```

Obviously inside the event handler the memoization hasn't happened yet but I need to access the memoized data in order to complete the handling of the event

The only way I can think to do this is have a `useEffect`, but I don't want the processing to happen every time `theData` changes, only in response to this specific event, so I would have to introduce a new state variable called `completeEventProcessingNow` and have the effect depend on that as well

The react docs (https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect) are pretty keen to point out that you shouldn't use `useEffect` to do things in response to user events but I don't see how else I can handle it in this case.

Comment: Please don't tag your titles. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I would implement recalculation of `memoizedData` wherever the data it depends on is being changed, so it would look like this:

```
const [theData, setTheData] = React.useState(null)
const [memoizedData, setMemoizedData] = React.useState(() => someComplexProcessOn(theData)) // note: https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#avoiding-recreating-the-initial-state

const buttonClick = async () => {
  const newData = await fetchTheData()
  setTheData(newData)

  const newMemoizedData = someComplexProcessOn(newData)
  setMemoizedData(newMemoizedData)
  // now I want to access memoizedData
  // you can access memoizedData in this function using newMemoizedData
  // or from other part of the code using memoizedData from state
}
```

or if the fetched data may not change (and you don't want to recalculate in such case) you can do:

```
const [theData, setTheData] = React.useState(null)
const [memoizedData, setMemoizedData] = React.useState(() => someComplexProcessOn(theData))

const buttonClick = async () => {
  const newData = await fetchTheData()
  setTheData((oldData) => {
    if (oldData !== newData) {
      const newMemoizedData = someComplexProcessOn(newData)
      setMemoizedData(newMemoizedData)
    }
    return newData
  })
}
```

Comment: Hmm this seems to go against one of the other cardinal react rules of never storing derived state in state variables. I guess there's no obvious solution for this

Answer (score 0):

FWIW (and unless another better answer appears) I ended up calling `someComplexProcessOn` once in the event handler to get the values I need right away, and then again in a `useMemo` to memoize them for subsequent renders. my processing wasn't so disastrously slow that I couldn't afford to call it twice.